# Updated version of tensorflow is not listed in "conda search"

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

Installed **tensorflow 1.5.0** with the command "conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow". Installation of the version is confirmed when I import it in Jupyter.
But when I did the 'conda search tensorflow' in anaconda prompt, following is the result:

> Conda search tensorflow

`(C:\Users\User\Anaconda3) C:\Users\User>conda search tensorflow
Fetching package metadata .............
r-tensorflow                 0.8.2                  r3.4.1_0  defaults
                             1.4              r342h0bf44f9_0  defaults
                             1.4.3            r343h889e2dd_0  defaults
                             1.4.3           mro343h889e2dd_0  defaults
tensorflow                   1.1.0               np112py35_0  defaults
                             1.1.0               np112py36_0  defaults
                             1.2.1                    py35_0  defaults
                             1.2.1                    py36_0  defaults
tensorflow-gpu               1.1.0               np112py35_0  defaults
                             1.1.0               np112py36_0  defaults`

*Can someone please throw light on the following:*

- Why isn't tensorflow 1.5.0 not listed above when it is being imported by default in Jupyter console?
- Values for all versions displayed above are set as "defaults".Why?
- How can I import different versions of tensorflow in different kernels?
- How could I verify if an imported version of tensorflow invokes GPU?

Comment: Why don't you just follow the [official installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#installing_with_anaconda) instead of using the conda-forge version?

Comment: Yes, that is an option. This is more of exploratory - How do we manage different versions of the package. Setting up different environments would enable multiple versions, but in this case there is no indication of environments. If we can install multiple versions, how do we invoke them in Jupyter, especially the GPU version.

Comment: By *How can I import different versions of tensorflow in different kernels?* do you mean with different versions of Python?

Comment: I meant the kernel that gets associated everytime a new session is started in Jupiter at console.

Answer (score 1):

`tensorflow 1.5.0` isn't listed in the output from `conda search tensorflow` because it isn't available on any of your default channels. Just as you needed to specify the conda-forge channel to the `conda install` command, you also need to tell `conda search` to look on the conda-forge channel:

```
conda search -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

In the output from that command you'll see that some packages are marked `conda-forge` instead of `defaults`, which answers your next question: `defaults` means that the listed package is available from one of your default search channels. You can change conda's default channel settings by editing the `.condarc` file, normally found in your home directory.

From your other questions, I think you may be confusing `conda search` with `conda list`.

- `conda search` shows the package versions **available to install**
- `conda list` shows the package versions **actually installed** in the
  current environment.

To use a specific version of a package in Jupyter you create a conda environment with that version, activate the environment, then start Jupyter:

```
activate myEnvironment
jupyter notebook
```

You may also be able to do this via the Anaconda Navigator or (on Windows) a start menu shortcut.

Comment: Great answers, Thank you!